# why am i getting this qsqldatabase errors

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qsqldatabase

I am having trouble while working with qsqldatabase. Here is my main code

```
 QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QPSQL");
    db.setHostName("acidalia");
    db.setDatabaseName("customdb");
    db.setUserName("mojito");
    db.setPassword("J0a1m8");
    bool ok = db.open();
    if(ok)
        qDebug() << "Successful";
    else
        qDebug() << "Unseccussful";
```

Here are my errors

[image]

Comment: add `QT += sql` in your .pro, and `#include <QSqlDatabase>` in your file.

Comment: Thanks, it worked successfully!